# Use REST API with CAML query to fetch the files inside multiple folders in single REST Call

Tags: angularjs, rest, cross-domain, sharepoint-2013, caml

I have a scenario where i would like to fetch all the files from multiple folders using REST API. I would like to filter the data in such a way so i can ignore the folders and fetch only the files inside all the files. I have the CAML query to do the recursive all activity but when i integrate with REST API its throwing a Bad request error. I checked the Network tab in IE it seems like the query in my code is not returning any data from REST API and it is failing when i use "GetItems". Could someone please let me know how to integrate CAML query in REST API.

```
var getContent = function (listTitle) {

                var deferred = $q.defer();

                if (listTitle == 'CandidateReports') {


  var query = appweburl + "_api/SP.AppContextSite("+ hostweburl +")/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/GetItems";



                var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
                executor.executeAsync({

                    url: query,
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    },
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        query: {
                            __metadata: {
                                type: "SP.CamlQuery"
                            },
                            ViewXml: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /> <FieldRef Name='Title' /> </ViewFields> <QueryOptions> <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' /> </QueryOptions> <Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /> <Value Type='Integer'>0</Value> </Eq>   </Where>"
                        }
                    }),
                    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                        console.log(data);
                        deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(data.body));
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        deferred.reject(JSON.parse(xhr.body).error);
                    }
                });

                return deferred.promise;

            };

            return {

                getContent: getContent

            };
```

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm also trying to implement CAML to Angular $http method...

Answer (score 0):

I think QueryOptions is not supported in client object model. why dont you try for the following approach

`<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /> <Value Type='Integer'>0</Value> </Eq> </Where></Query></View>`

P.S: I noticed the `<Query>` tag was missing in your CAML statement. Use CAML query builders for easy mapping of list fields.